# Can you merge 2 doujutsu? And can someone with prolonged and irriversable damage in their eyes have a successful eye transplant?

Tags: naruto

I was wondering if someone could merge 2 doujutsu and if someone who at avyoung age has their eyes damaged to the point of blindness and the damage being irriversable if someone with a doujutsu could transplant their eyes to the blind person so that they can see, I was wondering this because I plan too write a fan fiction about it and I wanted to make sure it is somewhat viable

Comment: We have a policy of 1 question per post here. Yours have 2 questions in it. Please edit to make it into 2 separate posts to comply with our policy. Welcome to Anime Stack Exchange.

Comment: Also said damage is caused by kunai senbon or shuriken

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know (and all the research I've made), no, you can't (as you called it) "merge" two, or more, Dōjutsus. You can have more than one at the same time, like Kaguya and her son Hagoromo.

I'm not saying it's not possible, but it just hasn't been seen in the universe of Naruto. And, as far as my knowledge goes, it hasn't been mentioned by Masashi-sensei either.

*Masashi-sensei has said once that if a Byakugan user and  Sharingan user have a kid the offspring would be born with a Sharingan in one eye and a Byakugan in the other but this isn't "merging" like you wanted*

For the next part of your question:

Yes, you can implant eyes to someone that has lost sight on that eye(s). The Uchiha are known do do it a lot, or they at least to it to "reach the next level" of power (in their eyes) but they are either almost or are blind when doing this.

Another huge example (of doing this) is Kakashi. He lost his eyesight on his left eyes, and then got a Sharingan, which is a Dōjutsu, implanted.

---

*I hope my answer helps, it's mostly what I know. I did try to find some references to help better but they were just about what Dōjutsu are and some examples and their abilities, which would be useless to you (according to what you asked, or was looking for, at least, so I did not include it).*

*I also hope your fan fiction goes well.*